# graphics card api that lets me draw to the screen

Tags: c++, gpu, nvidia

I have been learning cuda ( https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/ ), which is nvidia's gpgpu C++ libraries and it's great but there is one problem.

I want to do some graphics but cuda doesn't offer any "draw to screen/back-buffer" commands, does anyone know of any library I can use to draw graphics from kernels? (if you dont know what a kernel is, follow the link above)

additional info:
I have a Geforce MX150

Comment: This doesn't seems to be asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: the definition of software is "a set of computer instructions", that means libraries are software since they are made of computer instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CUDA is generally not targeted at graphical applications, but at computational ones, i.e. when using CUDA, a GPU is not used as a "Graphics Processing Unit", but as a massively parallel "Compute Accelerator". For graphical applications one would use one of the Graphics APIs like OpenGL, Direct3D and Vulkan.

That being said, one can combine CUDA and graphics APIs in a single application. There are multiple examples for CUDA interoperability with these graphics APIs in the official [cuda-samples](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples) repository, specifically under `Samples/5_Domain_Specific`. Some are called `simpleGL`, `simpleD3D12` and `simpleVulkan`.

As I am personally not well-versed with graphical applications, I cannot recommend which graphics API to choose or which example to look at.